# How can I use a camera on OTG in android

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, eclipse-juno, usb-otg

I am developing an android application that has to use two external cameras simultaneously. I want to know how can I use cameras. I have gone through many other answers but that were not clear. I want to get to know how to use camera in android

Comment: 'Webcams on OTG'? 'But that were on java'? Are you comparing OTG with java?

Comment: No I want to use external camera in android when the phone supports OTG. How can I make such an application.